# Python - How to read specific range of rows and columns from Google Sheet in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, google-sheets, rows

Have got a data similar like below in Google Sheet

[image]

Need to read data range starting from '*A4 to C4*' columns as fixed with countless rows(flexible) below in Python.
Help me out since I'm new to this Google Sheet with Python.

Expected Output in Python as Dataframe *df* is below:

```
Name    Row Class
AA      1   II
BB      2   I
CC      3   III
DD      4   II
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample scripts?

#### Sample script 1:

If your Spreadsheet is not published as the Web publish, how about the following script? In this sample script, I used googleapis for python. So, about how to use this, please check [Python Quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python). `service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)` in my proposed script is the same with the script of [Python Quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python).

```py
spreadsheet_id = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
range_a1Notation = "Sheet1!A4:C" # Please set the range as the A1Notation.

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_a1Notation).execute()
values = result.get("values", [])
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
```

#### Sample script 2:

If your Spreadsheet is published as the Web publish, you can use the following script.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-###/pub?sheet=Sheet1&range=A4%3AC&output=csv'
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content), sep=',')
```

- In this case, please replace `2PACX-###` for your Web published URL.
- `Sheet1` of `sheet=Sheet1` is the sheet name.
- `A4%3AC` of `range=A4%3AC` is the range `A4:C` as the A1Notation.

#### References:

- [Python Quickstart for Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: Thanks for your input. Have tried your Sample Script 1, getting error like 'Unable to parse range: Settings:B143'. Here, 'Settings' is my sheet name. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Little change(as mentioned) to the Sample Script 1 worked for me!

sheet_name = 'Settings'
range_a1Notation = sheet_name + '!B143:D'

Thank You for your help!

Comment: @user12345 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

With `openpyxl` it is easy and simple:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = 'your_path_to_file.xlsx')

sheet = wb['Your sheet name']
    for index, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows()):
        if index == "your specific index":
            "Do something"
```

[docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)